# How do I delete an image from the public using a form?

Tags: laravel

I programmed a product registration and together with it, I upload an image. This image is saved to public / storage / products. There is an input field that is to put the name of the image and the image is given this name and that name is saved in the database along with the image extension. I want to know how I delete this image from the public / storage / products folder when I click remove.

The method I tried below, didn't work
Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   
    $nameFile = $request->input('imageName', '');
    if($request->file('imageProduct')->isValid()){
        $nameFile .= '.' . $request->file('imageProduct')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->file('imageProduct')->storeAs('products', $nameFile);
    }

    $product = new Product();

    $product->name = $request->input('name');
    $product->price = $request->input('price');
    $product->imageName = $nameFile;

    $product->save(); 

    return redirect()->route('ProductControllerIndex');
}

public function destroy($id)
{   
    $products = Product::all();
    $filePathName = 'products/' . $products->imageName;
    if( file_exists($filePathName) ){
        unlink($filePathName);
    }
    // $delete = Product::find($id);
    // if(!$delete)
    //     return redirect()->route('ProductControllerCreate');
    
    // $delete->delete();
    // return redirect()->route('ProductControllerCreate');
}
```

}

view:

```
<form action="{{ route('ProductControllerDestroy', $product->id) }}" method="post">
   @csrf
   @method('DELETE')

   <input type="submit" value="Remover">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have add public path there. check below code.

```
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $filePathName = public_path().'/products/'. $products->imageName;
    if( file_exists($filePathName) ){
        unlink($filePathName);
    }
```

Comment: Also need to change `$products = Product::all();` to `$products = Product::find($id);`

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't focus on that.

Comment: It worked, vlw. I just had to change the path and the variable you put in the plural:  `$filePathName = public_path()./storage'/products/'. $product->imageName;`.

Comment: Deleting directly from the `public` path might cause errors in production because of the directory permissions, it's better to delete from the `storage` where the files actually get saved.

Comment: @HassanAzzam OP mention in question that he saved his image in public folder. not inside storage/public.

Comment: He's using `storeAs` which by default saves the files inside the storage directory

Answer (score 1):

The `storeAs` function stores the files inside `/storage/public`
Also in your `destroy` method you're calling `->imageName` on the `products` collection, you haven't find the product by it's id

so to delete the image the `distroy` method would look something like this

First you add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;` at the very top of the controller
then you add this `destroy` method

```
public function destroy($id)
{   
    $product = Product::find($id);
    Storage::delete('publuc/prodcuts/' . $product->imageName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your destroy method,

```
$products = Product::all();
$filePathName = 'products/' . $products->imageName;
if( file_exists($filePathName) ){
    unlink($filePathName);
}
```

If you are using [all()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#retrieving-models) then it will return an object with keys for multiple values(you can use `dd($products);` to check the object sent), thus you need a for loop to iterate through it.

```
$products = Product::all();
foreach($products as $product){
    $filePathName = 'products/' . $product->imageName;
    if( file_exists($filePathName) ){
        unlink($filePathName);
    }
}
```

If you want to access only the first value only (or will always have one value) then you can use this

```
$products = Product::first();
$filePathName = 'products/' . $products->imageName;
if( file_exists($filePathName) ){
    unlink($filePathName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change like this.

use `use File;` at the top.

```
public function destroy($id){ 

    $product = Product::find($id);
    $filePathName = public_path().'products/' . $product->imageName;

    if(File::exists($filePathName)){
        File::delete($filePathName);
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is this `File`?

Comment: @GabssRuizz Most of my Laravel project I use this style an it works fine till now.